# TEXTJOIN cells based on criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a sheet with the following columns:

[image: example data]

I'd like to be able to show, for a given experience, all the programs sorted into the following categories:

- Never done
- Done over 12 months ago
- Done 9-12 months ago
- Done 6-9 months ago
- Done 3-6 months ago

Ideally, the programs would be output into each category via a `TEXTJOIN` function, something like this:

[image: example output]

Comment: I don't see why *Berwick* appears in the **Silent Disco - Never** catagory.

Comment: Can you explain your categories?  Also how is "Glen Waverly" in "Never Done", wasn't that done Tuesday 19 December?

Comment: Sorry, the example output is only indicative of what I want it to look like, it's not accurate to the input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IF function in the TEXTJOIN and define the formula as an *array formula*. I give dummy references because it isn't clear in your screenshots. For example;

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IF($A$19:$A$25,$B$19:$B$25,""))
```

formula checks the TRUE/FALSE values in $A$19:$A$25 range and return a string from $B$19:$B$25 or an empty string based on TRUE and FALSE values respectively. *Please note that this is an **array formula** and you should press **Ctrl + Shift + Enter** instead of **Enter** only.*

I suggest you to create *helper columns* of TRUE/FALSE values at near columns of your table, for example; 1st column is for *Never*, and 2nd is for *Done over 12 months ago*, etc. So you can use each *helper column* in the **TEXTJOIN-IF** array function.

Comment: Thanks for this, it'll work for any Programs that have already done the Experience, but Programs that haven't done the Experience won't appear in the data at all. How would I reference, say, a list of all Programs and identify the ones that don't appear in the data, for the "Never" category?

Comment: You can use **MATCH** or **COUNTIF** function to check if a *Program* exists in your *Experience - Date - Program* table. For example; `=MATCH([Program Name],[Program Column in Table],0)` returns a number if there is a program or error if if there isn't.